# How to left align the tab text of TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, alignment, android-tablayout

I need to left align of the tab text inside tab layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    auto:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Comment: Check this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62715605/14806680

Answer (score 2):

You can either inflate a custom view in the tab layout as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896907/can-a-custom-view-be-used-as-a-tabitem)

or you can run a for loop over all tab items and set the gravity of indivisual textview inside the tab layout like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.view.setGravity(Gravity.START | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
app:tabGravity="start"
```